# how can I install GoDaddy SSL certificates for a new WSO2 keystore

Tags: wso2

the SSL zip file from GoDaddy contains two files

- GoDaddy Certificate Bundles - G2 With Cross to G1, includes Root (gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt)
- randomfile.crt (I'm assuming that is the my domain file.)

go daddy has a intermediate crt files here:
https://certs.godaddy.com/repository

from WSO2 docs they explain how to do this for Comodo CA

https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Creating+New+Keystores#CreatingNewKeystores-Step3:ImportCA-signedcertificatestokeystore

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias ExternalCARoot -file AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt -keystore newkeystore.jks -storepass mypassword

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias TrustCA -file COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt -keystore newkeystore.jks -storepass mypassword

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias SecureServerCA -file COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt -keystore newkeystore.jks -storepass mypassword

Please provide keytool commands to install GoDaddy certs, do I need itermediate files? which ones?

Thanks,
Brian.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the downloaded certificates from your vendor to .pem files.

```
openssl x509 -in <CERTIFICATE> -out <CERTIFICATE PEM>
```

Example:

```
openssl x509 -in server.crt -out server.pem
```

Create a certificate chain with the root and intermediate certifications.

```
cat <CERTIFCATE 1> <CERTIFICATE 2> ... >> <CERTIFICATE CHAIN>
```

Example:

```
cat intermediate.pem root_crt.pem >> clientcertchain.pem
```

or else you can do this by copying the body of each certificate into one text file in the following order.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(Your Intermediate certificate) 
-----END CERTIFICATE----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(Your Root certificate) 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Export the SSL certificate chain file as a PKCS12 file with "wso2carbon" as the alias.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out <KEYSTORE>.p12 -inkey <SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY>.key -in <SERVER_PUBLIC_CERTIFICATE>.crt -CAfile clientcertchain.pem -name "<alias>"
```

Example:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out KEYSTORE.p12 -inkey server_private_key.key -in server_public_certificate.crt -CAfile clientcertchain.pem -name "wso2carbon"
```

Please note that *server_private_key.key* and *server_public_certificate.crt* should be your server private key and public certificate.

Then to import the generated P12 extension files into newly created keystore

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore KEYSTORE.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore <KEY_STORE_NAME>.jks
```

Comment: This is it. with some changes i manage to accomplish it. I added all steps as a answer thanks mate. up-voted.

Answer (score 1):

Phew. Just now Completed the Installation. 
Basically here are the steps you need to follow. Below are the steps taken from the beginning.

1. Create Keystore and the CSR

   keytool -genkey -alias certalias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore newkeystore.jks
2. Create CSR - copy output and submit to Go Daddy.

keytool -certreq -alias certalias -keystore newkeystore.jks

3. Get the Certificates for tomcat you will get below certificates.

   - gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt - Root Certificate
   - gdig2.crt.pem - Intermediate Certificate
   - [randomNumber].crt - Domain Certificate
4. Then Prathap's Steps. Convert crt to pem.

   - openssl x509 -in gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -out gd_bundle-g2-g1.pem
   - openssl x509 -in [randomNumber].crt -out [randomNumber].pem
5. Join root and intermediate certificate

   cat gdig2.crt.pem gd_bundle-g2-g1.pem >> clientcertchain.pem
6. Extract the key from the keystore.

   - keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore newkeystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcalias keys -deststorepass 
     -destkeypass
   - openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12  -nodes -nocerts -out key.pem
7. create pkcs12 keystore

   openssl pkcs12 -export -out final.p12 -inkey key.pem -in [randomNumber].crt -CAfile clientcertchain.pem -name "cacertificates"
8. Create JKS from pkcs keystore.

   keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore final.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore wso2carbon.jks
9. Replace it with wso2carbon.jks located in `<WSO2ESB_HOME>/repository/resources/security/`
10. go to `<WSO2ESB_HOME>/repository/resources/security/`
11. Extract key file to add client keystore

    keytool -export -alias cacertificates -keystore newkeystore.jks -file .pem
12. Add key to `client-truststore.jks`

    keytool -import -alias cacertificates -file .pem -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon